# Play Free Online Camera In Android App

Tags: android, video

I am trying to load the following free online camera in my app (site: http://www.earthcam.com)
for example, [this video](http://www.earthcam.com/usa/illinois/chicago/field/?cam=fieldmuseum).
and I found the video address by IDM (http://video3.earthcam.com/fecnetwork/5187.flv/chunklist_w664887517.m3u8)

I loaded the video in my app with the following code:

```
String VideoURL = "http://video3.earthcam.com/fecnetwork/5187.flv/chunklist_w664887517.m3u8";
MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);
        videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoview.start();
        }
    });
```

Now I have two problems

1. How can I play the video in my app with the original url(for example [www.earthcam.com/usa/illinois/chicago/field/?cam=fieldmuseum](http://www.earthcam.com/usa/illinois/chicago/field/?cam=fieldmuseum))
2. How can I display all tools (zoom in, zoom out, volume, stop, pause, like, view, map, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question why the video is not playing: the support of a livestream in MediaController is limited. I would suggest you to ExoPlayer https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer
It should handle a livestream playback.

Second question: in order to display all tools that you mentioned you would need an access to the control of the camera either via API or via URL parameters. Then you would need to add this buttons as an overlay on top of the video player and connect buttons to the API calls. However, I don't think that EarthCam provides public API for a camera control.

Comment: Yes, you can download a code for a web page, but why would you want to do that? Livestream video will not be downloaded by the webpage...

Comment: I can't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve at the end? You can download html, css and compiled javascript for this particular page, but you wouldn't be able to run a similar page on your localhost or mobile app.

Comment: Do you mean in a WebView?